# String was not recognized a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net-core

I have a Stored Procedure that return both NULL and a proper Date value for a DATE column in the result.
However, I am getting the error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' while converting the NULL values in the result. Other proper date values are converting fine.

```
var dataList = new List<Model>();
while (sqlDataReader != null && await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync())
{
    dataList.Add(new Model
    {
        MyDate = DateTime.Parse(sqlDataReader["DateColumn"].ToString()),
    });
}
```

Below is the model-

```
public class AgreementTrackingReportViewModel
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

SP returns value like

```
NULL
2019-01-28
```

Comment: What's the value of DateTime.Parse(sqlDataReader["DateColumn"].ToString(). If sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] is NULL then DateTime.Parse will fail.

Comment: sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] can have both NULL and 2019-01-28 values

Comment: Any way to make it work for both values?

Comment: null sqlDataReader["DateColumn"].ToString() return string 'null' ,  you better handle sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] =DbNull. value?  default date : sqlDataReader["DateColumn"]...  I assume your column string type

Comment: If it's a `DATE`, the result is already `DateTime`, or else it's `DBNull.Value`. There's no need to bounce it through a string back and forth again, especially since date formatting is locale dependent. Depending on your version of C# there are more and less elegant ways of writing this test, but I'd just use Dapper instead of writing boilerplate like this.

Comment: What is the db type of the column you are accessing? Otherwise we are guessing and converting for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
MyDate = sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] == DBNull.Value
    ? null
    : (DateTime?)sqlDataReader["DateColumn"]
```

If your column is a valid DATE SQL column, it should be converted to DateTime.

Make sure you check for [`DBNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value). It can also be done with [`Convert.IsDBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull) or [`SqlDataReader.IsDBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull) methods.

If your stored procedure converts your dates and NULLs in "DateColumn" to (n)varchar for some weird reason, you can try this code:

```
MyDate = sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] == DBNull.Value
         ||
         sqlDataReader["DateColumn"] == "NULL"
    ? null
    : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse((string)sqlDataReader["DateColumn"])
```

Comment: Same error for NULL values

Comment: Unless it's `NULL`, in which case it's `DBNull.Value`, and converting that to `DateTime?` will fail. `DbDataReader` hails from a more innocent time where `Nullable` did not exist, which is why there's a separate `.IsDBNull` method.

Comment: @OlexanderIvanitskyi no luck

Comment: @st1612 what's the error this time?

Comment: same error String was not recognized a valid DateTime

Comment: Your DATE column is probably converted to (N)VARCHAR in the stored procedure.

Comment: @st1612 try the last one if it is.

Comment: Otherwise, your stored procedure might convert NULL values to `"NULL"` strings, you can try that check too))